# Azure AD User: Assigned Roles vs Azure Role Assignments

Tags: azure-active-directory

In a specific user's section of Azure AD, there are two menu items that seem to mean the same thing to me even though the data is different. Can someone explain the difference between
Assigned Roles and Azure Role Assignments?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Assigned roles** are **Azure AD** administrator roles, for accessing Azure AD and other Microsoft 365 platforms such as Exchange and SharePoint.

[Azure AD built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference)

**Azure role assignments** (may also be referred to as Azure RBAC roles) are for accessing **Azure** resources such as virtual machines, storage accounts, subscriptions, etc.

[Azure built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles)

**Azure** and **Azure AD** are different terms for 2 distinct platforms

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying but I want to clarify. Can Azure be considered the "[classic subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles)" and Azure AD the "Current subscription"? Is classic subscription another term for [ABAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/conditions-overview) and Current subscription for [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)?